# What would trigger a "due on transfer" clause when transferring property ownership to an LLC?

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company, rental-property

I plan on co-owning a rental property. Soon after closing, the plan is to transfer the title to an LLC for some liability protection and our lender has assured us that the *due on transfer* clause won't take effect. In fact, he says in 18 years of lending he's never seen a due on transfer clause trigger for anyone.

So what are the kinds of things that actually **would** trigger the due on transfer? Everything I've Googled talks about how rare it is but not what would actually cause it.

Comment: Isn't the triggering of the clause a prerogative of the Lender? I don't think it is automatic.

Comment: Why not just have the LLC buy the property?  From what I understand that is preferable.

Comment: @PeteBelford because noone will lend money to the LLC

Answer (score 3):

The fact that they "never saw" it happening doesn't mean it cannot happen. Transferring ownership to a LLC is transferring to a different legal entity (as opposed, for example, to putting your property into a living trust). Thus it is in fact a valid trigger to call on the loan for lenders. Whether they actually do it or not is up to them, but I wouldn't rely on one clerk claiming he never saw it happening.